# Google App Engine - Search for stringProperty in python

Tags: python, string, google-app-engine, properties

I am new Google App Engine so I followed the HelloWorld and Guestbook tutorial for Python to start with.

Now I would like to query for a specific string in my class but I can not find the appropriate doc in GAE documentation.

I have the following :

```
class song_key(genre)
    #We use genre as the key for a Song entity
    return ndb.Key('Repository',genre)

class Singer(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    birthday = ndb.DateProperty()

class Song(ndb.Model):
    author = ndb.StructuredProperty(Singer)
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    release = ndb.DateProperty()
    dateAdd = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

I would like to find all the songs where author == 'John Lennon' assuming they all belong to the same 'genre'

I tried some things like :

```
q = Song.query((Song.author.name == "John Lennon'), ancestor=song_key(genre)).order(-Song.data)
results = q.all()
```

But this is clearly not the way to do this query.

Can somebody help me to understand the queries in Google App Engine ? What is the good way to achieve such a stringProperty query ?

I have went through https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries or https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass but I have some issue understanding the whole concept ^^

EDIT : Here's the result of two queries :

```
Query(kind='Song', ancestor=Key('Repository', 'Pop'), orders=...)

[Song(key=Key('Repository', 'Pop', 'Song', 5733953138851840), author=Singer(name=u'John Lennon'), date=datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 13, 22, 59, 31, 766373),title=u'Come Together'), Song(key=Key('Repository', 'Pop', 'Song', 5556931766779904), author=Singer(name=u'Bruno Mars'), date=datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 13, 16, 15, 58, 584174), title=u'Uptown Funk), Song(key=Key('Repository', 'Pop', 'Song', 6119881720201216), author=Singer(name=u'Katty Perry'), date=datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 13, 16, 15, 30, 915749), title=u'Teenage Dream')]
```

I have three entries.

And when I want to filter by author's name :

```
Query(kind='Song', ancestor=Key('Repository', 'Pop'), filters=FilterNode('author.name', '=', 'John Lennon'), orders=...)

[]
```

Empty list !

Thank you !

Comment: Why is this "clearly" not the way? And why have you made the singer properties indexed=False if you want to query them?

Comment: and what is class song_key()  supposed to be doing.  That is somewhat bizarre

Comment: I started from the guestbook tutorial https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingdatastore but you are completely right. I made the singer properties indexed :) song_key() is the "genre" of a music entity. Like the "guestbook_key" in the guestbook tutorial, I use the song key to gather all my song entries under different "genre" categories.

I also add a result of my query.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a pythonic way to solve my problem :
I query ALL the songs in a specific genre, then I check if the singer I am looking for belongs to this list.

```
q = Song(ancestor=repository_key(genre))
results = p.fetch()

songs = []
for result in results:
    if author in result.author.name:
        songs.append(result)
```